# where are visual studio 2017 dialog editor tools and controls?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a complete newbie to Visual Studio 2017 and now need to update a old windows application.  I down loaded VS 2017 community, found my .RC files and used it to open one of my dialog designs.  It displays correctly but my problem is how do I get the VS to display the tools such as grid lines, alignment tools, etc?  And how do I display the menu of the various controls (boxes and items) that one can add to the dialog design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are in the toolbox pane/sidebar/thingie on the side. If you don't see it, go to the View menu and select "Toolbox" to turn it on.

Comment: And for any other dunces such as myself, the grid and alignment controls are at the top.  I also had problems displaying the dialog and the tool bar at the same time.  Turns out one can move the tool bar but not the dialog.